# run a function when another ends, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, completion

Im trying to call a function when another one ends but I keep getting an error that tells me the image is not above 0 pixels high and wide so I presume it hasn't got the image before the function is called. when I add a breakpoint where the function to call the OCR the app doesn't show the image on the screen at this point which is why I came to that conclusion.

here is the error I get from the ocr.

> NSAssert( widthOfImage > 0 && heightOfImage > 0, @"Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide");

below is my console readout where I placed prints to see the flow.

> Tony 1 Requested....
>   Tony 3 run OCR....
>   Tony 2 Handle Rectangle....
>   Tony: Corected image here......
>   (lldb)

Below is my code. should i have in a completion that makes sure the function is not called until the image is in place?.

```
func startOCR() {
        swiftOCRInstance.recognize(correctedImageView.image!) {recognizedString in
            print(recognizedString)
            self.classificationLabel.text = recognizedString
        }
    }


lazy var rectanglesRequest: VNDetectRectanglesRequest = {
    print("Tony 1 Requested....")
    return VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangles)



}()

func handleRectangles(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation]
        else { fatalError("unexpected result type from VNDetectRectanglesRequest") }
    guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.classificationLabel.text = "No rectangles detected."
        }
        return
    }
    let imageSize = inputImage.extent.size

    // Verify detected rectangle is valid.
    let boundingBox = detectedRectangle.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize)
    guard inputImage.extent.contains(boundingBox)
        else { print("invalid detected rectangle"); return }

    // Rectify the detected image and reduce it to inverted grayscale for applying model.
    let topLeft = detectedRectangle.topLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let topRight = detectedRectangle.topRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomLeft = detectedRectangle.bottomLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomRight = detectedRectangle.bottomRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let correctedImage = inputImage
        .cropped(to: boundingBox)
        .applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
            "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
            "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
            "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
            "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight)
            ])
    //          .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [
    //                kCIInputSaturationKey: 0,
    //                kCIInputContrastKey: 32
    //            ])


    // Show the pre-processed image
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.correctedImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: correctedImage)
        if self.correctedImageView.image != nil {
            print("Tony 2 Handle Rectangle....")
            print("Tony: Corected image here......")

        }else {
            print("Tony: No corected image......")
        }

    }
    print("Tony 3 run OCR....")
    self.startOCR()
}
```

I also get a purple error the says the UIImage should be used on the main thread in the pic below...

[image]

Comment: That error is telling you `UIImageView` should be used from the main thread, not `UIImage`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the main thread whenever you're working with `UIImageView`, or any other UIKit class (unless otherwise noted, such as when constructing UIImages on background threads).

You can use `GCD` to do this on the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //Handle UIKit actions here
}
```

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview)

> **Threading Considerations:** 
>   Manipulations to your application’s user
>   interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call
>   the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread
>   of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary
>   is when creating the view object itself, but all other manipulations
>   should occur on the main thread.

Comment: I have added dispatch main queue to the function and this removes the purple error. but It is still failing when calling the function with the same fail.   NSAssert( widthOfImage > 0 && heightOfImage > 0, @"Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide");